# How do I wire receptacles for a washer and dryer on a new circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I need to add a new circuit that will have only 2 receptacles, one for a washer and another one for a dryer. This will be a 20 amp circuit. Can someone please tell me how to wire the two outlets together? I have experience with changing outlets but never added an outlet from another one and want to make sure I wire everything correctly before calling over an inspector to check the work.

Comment: One of those should better be a GFCI receptacle (unless the circuit itself has a GFCI breaker)

Comment: @ratchetfreak -  I thought a GFCI was only required for a laundry room outlet if it's within 6 ft of a laundry sink. If no sink then it's not required. Or are you speaking of a best-practice recommendation for safety to use a GFCI outlet even if it's not strictly required by the NEC?

Comment: @Johnny best practice, [and we just had a question where the thing was useful](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/how-can-i-find-out-why-my-washing-machine-trips-the-outlet). Also depends on jurisdiction; in Belgium the laundry room is part of the "wet area" which requires a 30mA GFCI (rest of the house needs a common 300mA)

Comment: @ratchetfreak
Electrical motors often nuisance trip GFCI outlets (see http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26745/how-can-i-stop-this-gfci-receptacle-from-tripping).
I had to remove my GFCI outlet as it was incompatible with the washer.

Comment: @gbronner You could try a different break time rated GFCI instead, a G type will break immediately while a S or T type will delay and allow the current to stabilize.

Comment: What sort of dryer are you going to run with 20 amps? Most driers are 220/30 amp

Comment: @ratchetfreak, a GFI is not required unless there is a sink. Also, what makes you think this job is in Belgium??

Comment: @EricGunnerson, a gas dryer.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey better to have one and not need it then need one and get killed by a ground fault.

Comment: Well then state that it's your opinion to install one. It's only required under certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Wire from the panel to the closest outlet.  Use Ratchet Freak's recommendation of using a GFCI since this has a potential to become a wet location.  Put the GFCI at the first outlet location and wire the line/feed side of the outlet to the wire running from the panel.  Add a second wire that will chain the second outlet to this outlet.  On the GFCI, the second wire will attach to the load side of the outlet and the other end will wire to a normal outlet.

For a 20 amp circuit, you will be using at minimum 12 gauge wire.  Make sure the wires are anchored to the studs outside the box and they are running through the middle of the studs to protect from screws/nails.  If you have to notch a stud to run the wires, make sure you add a nail plate over the notch.

Comment: Is there a reason a GFCI protected 5-20T duplex outlet cannot be used here? To me, it would make more sense to have a single duplex outlet in this case *unless* you anticipate loads such as a clothes iron being plugged in here...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I'm assuming from his question that the washer and dryer will not be side to side as they typically are.  I've been in plenty of homes where they are either facing each other on opposite walls or in a corner with a water heater between them.  Sometimes you just have to work with the layout you are given.

Comment: Why a GFI? If there is a laundry sink in the area then yes, it is required, but if not what do you think is being gained by the GFI. And NO, without a sink it is NOT considered a wet area. And WHY in the world would a 5-20R be needed???

Comment: @diceless -- understandable

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- 210.8(A)(10) in the 2014 NEC calls out laundry areas without regard to the presence of a laundry sink.  The 5-20T was simply a suggestion based on the use of a single duplex receptacle on a 20A circuit -- I'd be fine with a pair of 5-15 duplex receptacles instead.